# To extract information from IFC file using ifcopenshell

Tags: python-2.7, extract, ifc

I am working on extracting data from an IFC file using ifcopenshell. Till now I have extracted the entities that are needed i.e I have extracted structural model from architectural model.
But now the main problem is that I want to obtain information from my IFC file. I want to ask questions from ifcopenshell like-

How many columns are there?

What is the total area of the structure?

What is the size of the column?

What is the loading on column?

These are some of the questions that i am expecting from ifcopenshell to answer. I need this information further for designing.
Any help that can point me right direction will really be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be possible to answer all those questions.

> How many columns are there?

Query for IfcColumn and count the size of the result set. This might be inaccurate if objects that should be columns aren't typed as columns.

> What is the total area of the structure?

This might be given as property to the complete model (if the creator of the file included that information). If not you can try to get an estimation based on model size. The third option would be to see if there are annotations/measurements or a 2D floor plan in the file and use those informations.

> What is the size of the column?

Again look for properties. Model size might not be appropriate as it is based on *what is displayed*. For design different sizes/measurements are probably relevant (I am not an architect, so I don't know about building design).

> What is the loading on column?

This information is probably only available through properties. A look at http://www.buildingsmart-tech.org/ifc/IFC4/Add2TC1/html/link/ifccolumn.htm at the standard properties doesn't reveal a property relating to your question - so either load information is included in a custom property by the program/creator of that IFC file or you need an external source. IfcOpenShell only does IFC file parsing and geometry rendering, no additional calculations.